# Overriding function in prototype of custom element changes the this object

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I made a custom element class and then tried to wrap one of the functions at the prototype level so every instance would use the wrapper. However, when I do this, the value of `this` changes inside the function. How can I change a prototype function and access the instance `this` inside of the new function?

In this example, every time I log `this` in `MyClass2` I expect it to print `<my-class-2></my-class-2>`, just like when I log `this` in `MyClass` it prints `<my-class></my-class>`.

[Here's a fiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/Lv73zw1e/15/).

```js
class MyClass extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Inside MyClass:')
        console.log(this)
    }
}

customElements.define('my-class', MyClass)


class MyClass2 extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Inside MyClass2:')
        console.log(this)
    }
}

let connectedCallback = MyClass.prototype.connectedCallback
MyClass2.prototype.connectedCallback = () => {
    console.log('Outside MyClass2')
    console.log(this)
    connectedCallback()
}

customElements.define('my-class-2', MyClass2)
```

```html
<my-class></my-class>
<my-class-2></my-class-2>
```

Console output:

```
Inside MyClass:
<my-class>​</my-class>​
Outside MyClass2
Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: global, …}
Inside MyClass:
undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you redefine the `connectedCallback()` method, you **must not** use an arrow function, because arrow function calls won't set the value of `this` to the reference of the object.

That's generally an advantage, but not here. Instead use the classic `function ()` notation:

```
 MyClass2.prototype.connectedCallback = function() {
     console.log(this)
 }
```

Second, when you write `let connectedCallback = MyClass.prototype.connectedCallback` actually you disconnect the referenced function from the object.

As a consequence, `this` won't reference the object from where it is call but the current context which is `window`.

Instead, you can use `bind()` to set `this` with the value of the object, before calling the method:

```
 MyClass2.prototype.connectedCallback = function() {
     connectedCallback.bind(this)()
 }
```

Alternately, you could define the function as a method of the current object.

```
 MyClass2.prototype.connectedCallback_old = MyClass.prototype.connectedCallback
 MyClass2.prototype.connectedCallback = function() {
     this.connectedCallback_old()
 }
```

```js
class MyClass extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Inside MyClass:')
        console.log(this)
    }
}

customElements.define('my-class', MyClass)


class MyClass2 extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('Inside MyClass2:')
        console.log(this)
    }
}

let connectedCallback = MyClass.prototype.connectedCallback
MyClass2.prototype.connectedCallback = function () {
    console.log('Outside MyClass2')
    console.log(this)
    connectedCallback.bind(this)()
}

customElements.define('my-class-2', MyClass2)
```

```html
<my-class></my-class>
<my-class-2></my-class-2>
```

Comment: I did not know that arrow functions didn't set `this`. This works great! I am using `call()`/`apply()` instead of `bind()`.

Comment: You are right. Call is better than bind in this case. I forgot these methods.